A question on cyclotomic extension of finite field.
Let $\mathbb F$ a finite field with $q$ elements. In addition, let $\zeta$ be a primitive $n$-th root of unity such that $\zeta\notin\mathbb F$. I want to prove that if $n\mid q^2-1$ but $n\nmid q-1$, then $\lambda=\zeta+\zeta^{-1}\in\mathbb F$.
My attempt: I want to show that $[\mathbb F(\lambda):\mathbb F]=1$. We have that
$$
[\mathbb F(\zeta):\mathbb F(\lambda)][\mathbb F(\lambda):\mathbb F]
=[\mathbb F(\zeta):\mathbb F]
$$
Since $x^2-\lambda x+1=(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^{-1})$ and since $\zeta\notin\mathbb F$, it follows that $[\mathbb F(\zeta):\mathbb F(\lambda)]=2$. How do I prove that $[\mathbb F(\zeta):\mathbb F]=2$ ?

If $n\mid q^2-1$ then $\zeta\in\mathbb{F}_{q^2}$ and the rest follows.

Thanks @schiepy. The assertion follows since  then $\mathbb F_{q^2}\cong \mathbb F(\zeta)$, so $[\mathbb F(\zeta):\mathbb F]=2$ ?

Yeah, but you need to explain that $[\mathbb{F}_q(\zeta):\mathbb{F}_q]\neq 1$ which follows from $n\nmid q-1$.

Boaz, do you think this is a refined/repeated version of your previous question on the same theme? Or what? I'm inclined to vote to close the earlier as a duplicate of this one, but it could go either way. I chose to answer this version instead of commenting, because the matter was apparently still unclear. Or I'm missing something, and the two questions are actually different?

Thanks @Jyrki Lahtonen for your answer. The previous question regarded the converse of a similar problem, so it is not the same. Regarding your answer, I have still some problems (see below).

Let's be a bit careful here. The claim is actually false as stated. The fact that $\zeta\in\Bbb{F}_{q^2}\setminus\Bbb{F}_q$ only implies that $\zeta+\zeta^q\in\Bbb{F}_q$. There is no reason to think that $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ would be an element of the base field. In other words, there is the possibility that $\Bbb{F}(\zeta)=\Bbb{F}(\lambda)=\Bbb{F}_{q^2}$.
For an explicit example consider the case $q=3$, $n=8$. If $i\in\Bbb{F}_9$ satisfies the equation $i^2=-1$, then $\zeta=1+i$ is easily shown to be a root of unity of order $8=q^2-1$. We have $1/\zeta=-1+i$, so $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}=2i=-i\notin\Bbb{F}_3$.
The Galois group is generated by the Frobenius automorphism, so the other root of the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ is $\zeta^q$. We thus see that the conjugate of $\zeta$ is equal to $\zeta^{-1}=\zeta^q$ if and only if $\zeta^{q+1}=1$. In other words $\lambda\in\Bbb{F}_q$ only when $n\mid q+1$.
Of course, as Schiepy explained, $n\mid q^2-1$, $n\nmid q-1$ together imply that
$\Bbb{F}_{q^2}=\Bbb{F}_q(\zeta)$, so the minimal polynomial of $\zeta$ over $\Bbb{F}_q$ is the quadratic
$$(x-\zeta)(x-\zeta^q)=x^2-[\zeta+\zeta^q]x+\zeta^{q+1}.$$
We see that the coefficients $c_1=\zeta+\zeta^q$ and $c_0=\zeta^{q+1}$ here are in the base field by checking that they are fixed points of the Frobenius:
$$
\begin{aligned}
c_1^q&=[\zeta+\zeta^q]^q=\zeta^q+\zeta^{q^2}=\zeta^q+\zeta=c_1,\\
c_0^q&=(\zeta^{q+1})^q=\zeta^{q^2+q}=\zeta^{q^2}\cdot\zeta^q=\zeta\cdot\zeta^q=c_0.
\end{aligned}
$$

Mind you, cyclotomic extensions are everywhere in the realm of finite fields. Remember that every non-zero element of every finite field is a root of unity.
But the situation is still a bit different from the case of cyclotomic extensions of $\Bbb{Q}$, where it does follow $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ belongs to a proper subfield of $\Bbb{Q}(\zeta)$ whenever $\zeta$ is a root of unity of order $n>2$. The different behavior is explained by the fact that over $\Bbb{Q}$ ALL the roots of unity of a fixed order are each others Galois conjugates, and "complex conjugation"
$\zeta\mapsto \zeta^{-1}$ is always an automorphism of order two, hence its fixed point $\zeta+\zeta^{-1}$ belongs to a proper subfield. In the case of finite fields the roots of unity of a given order are no longer all each others Galois conjugates, and it is possible that there is no field automorphism mapping $\zeta$ to $\zeta^{-1}$.
It all fits together by Galois theory. The Galois group of a cyclotomic extension of $\Bbb{Q}$ is always abelian, but usually not cyclic. On the other hand, the Galois group of an extension of finite fields is always cyclic.

In the last paragraph I made an educated guess as to what may have lead the asker to make a wrong turn not following the correct path.

Great catch, I didn't notice that the claim is actually false!
